# Python Dictionary append value error

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I'm trying to append a value (list) to a dictionary unsuccessfully. setting the value by 'equal' works, but appending doesn't.

```
DurationDict = dict()
DurationDict[str(curYear)] = duration  // This works
DurationDict[str(curYear)].append(duration) //This does't work.
```

any ideas?

Comment: you can `append` to a `list` but not to a `dict`. here is the [python doc for dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: you can only append to a value of a key if value is of type list.

Comment: you code equal to "duration.append(duration)", you should make sure duration is a list

Comment: So, you didn't even try to check the documentation before you asked this question?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to append to the value of dictionary, then value should be a type of `list`.

lets consider following example:

```
>>> k = {"a":1}
>>> k["b"] = 2
>>> k["c"] = [2]
>>> k["c"].append("new value") # here you can append because value of c is type of list.
>>> print(k)
{'a': 1, 'c': [2, 'new value'], 'b': 2}
>>> k["b"].append("new value") # here you can not append because value of b is type of int
```

Answer (score 2):

you can append to a `list` but not to a `dict`. python `dict`s are [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

if you want to have a `list` for all your dictionary entries, you can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict):

```
collections import defaultdict

DurationDict = defaultdict(list)
DurationDict[str(curYear)].append(duration)
```

`defaultdict` works like a normal `dict` except it returns the result of the 'factory' - in this case `list()` if the key you are looking up does not exist yet. you can then append to this (empty) list.

Comment: This answer would be much improved if you explained to the OP why their attempt did not work, and why this solves their problem (because this is the correct solution to the OP's issue, I believe).

Comment: @SethMMorton: good point. added a short explanation. why the OP's approach does not work is in my first comment to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can only append `lists`. If you have an empty dictionary `d`,

```
d = {} # initialize an empty dictionary
d['a'].append(1) # will NOT work
```

But if you already had an empty `list` defined,

```
d = {'a': []} # initialize with an empty list
df['a'].append(1) # will work

>>> d
{'a': [1]}
```